# I cannot change the values of a column using python pandas

Tags: python, pandas, string, variables, integer

I am working with the [UCI adult dataset][1]. I have added a row as a header to facilitate operation. I need to change the last column, which can take two values, '<=50k' and '>50k' and whose name is 'etiquette'. I have tried the following

```
num_datos.loc[num_datos.loc[:,"etiquette"]=="<=50K", "etiquette"]=1 
num_datos.loc[num_datos.loc[:,"etiquette"]==">50K", "etiquette"]=0
```

and the following

```
num_datos['etiquette'].replace(['<=50K'], 1)
num_datos['etiquette'].replace(['>50K'], 0)
```

However, this seems to do nothing, since if I then execute

```
print(num_datos.etiquette[0])
```

I still get a value of  `<=50K`. Is there a way for me to replace the values of the column in question?

Answer (score 1):

Your second try, using df.replace(), should work when you remove the square brackets from your string. So instead use:

```
    num_datos['etiquette'].replace('<=50K', 1)
    num_datos['etiquette'].replace('>50K', 0)
```

The function currently interprets ['<=50K'] as a list with one element, and cannot find any values in your dataframe that are a list with that element. Instead, you want it to look for the string.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Hello. Thanks for the answer. However, I am afraid I have copied your suggested solution, but I still have the problem.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. A different question then, did you assign the result back to num_datos? As in: 
num_datos = num_datos['etiquette'].replace('<=50K', 1)